# How can I change the routing url within a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm using formik in a react project and onSubmit I want to change the route .
This is form code :

```
const onSubmit = (values) => {
        props.test(values);
        history.replaceState('/result');

    };
    return (
        <div className="container mt-5">
            <Formik initialValues={initialValues} validationSchema={validationSchema} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <Form>
                            <p className="p-0 m-0 pr-1">Name</p>
                            <Field className="ml-3 field" name="name" placeholder="Name" />

                            <p className="p-0 m-0 pr-3">Age</p>
                            <Field className="ml-4 field" name="age" placeholder="Age" />

                            <p className="p-0 m-0">Height</p>
                            <Field className="ml-3 field" name="height" placeholder="Height in meters" />

                            <p className="p-0 m-0">Weight</p>
                            <Field className="ml-3 field" name="weight" placeholder="Weight in kilograms" />

                            <button className="submit mt-3" type="submit">
                                Submit
                            </button>
                </Form>
            </Formik>
```

When I click the submit button I want to url to change but instead I get an error which is :

```
Unexpected use of 'history'  no-restricted-globals
```

How can I change the url within onSubmit function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with this code :

```
props.history.push('/result');
```